# CFX wadl2java problem generating java

Tags: java, wadl

Hi I'm trying to generate the Java classes that are defined in the following WADL

http://www.epo.org/searching/free/ops.html

I'm trying to do it by command line. I've download the WADL and the XSD and also the apache-cfx-2.4.2.

I've tried to run the following command:

wadl2java" -verbose ops.wadl

I'm getting this error:

```
org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wadlto.jaxrs.JAXRSContainer.execute(JAXRSContainer.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wadlto.WADLToJava.run(WADLToJava.java:65)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wadlto.WADLToJava.run(WADLToJava.java:57)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wadlto.WADLToJava.main(WADLToJava.java:99)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.codegen.SourceGenerator.createCodeModel(SourceGenerator.java:914)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.codegen.SourceGenerator.generateSchemaCodeAndInfo(SourceGenerator.java:182)
```

Does anyone know how to generate Java Classes from WADL without using Maven (I haven't got the permission to use it)?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the XSD's and generating the code from there.
I used the JAXB xcj command.

Comment: your wadl is invalid, SoapUI complains about it as well, that's why CXF can't parse it. Please give valid answers to questios , even if they are your own

Comment: Hi, @AndreiBodnarescu thanks for your input. The wadl isn't mine. I was just trying to use it. I also didn't knew it was invalid until you said so, so thanks. The answer I gave was in fact the way I managed the problem to get a working solution and my only motivation to post it was to present a workaround if someone needs it.